# How to reset mouse acceleration/sensitivity to default on Ubuntu Mate 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate

How to reset mouse acceleration/sensitivity to the defaults on Ubuntu Mate 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to MATE Control Center → Mouse (or execute `mate-mouse-properties`) and then set needed values:

[image: mate-mouse-properties]

or programmatically with `dconf`:

```
dconf reset -f /org/mate/desktop/peripherals/mouse/
```

Comment: also works on ubuntu mate 22.04